# If a real symmetric matrix has two diagonal entries of opposite sign, it has two eigenvalues of opposite sign?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given an $n × n$ real symmetric matrix, with atleast two diagonal entries that are of opposite sign, does this matrix have both a positive eigenvalue and a negative eigenvalue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, because the corresponding quadratic form is indefinite; it takes
both positive and negative values.

Comment: Right, if we take $y = e_k$, the quadratic form would be $a_{kk}$, if the real symmetric matrix was $A = [a_{ij}]_{i,j=1}^n$.